# map with kwargs returning nonetype python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, nonetype, keyword-argument

Say I had a function, like this:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args, kwargs)
```

And I wanted to call it in a map object, like this:

```
obj = map(lambda var: test(var+1, var = var), [1, 2, 3])
```

When I print the values in it, it shows this:

```
>>> for i in obj:
    print(i)


(2,) {'var': 1}
None
(3,) {'var': 2}
None
(4,) {'var': 3}
None
```

Where are the `None` values coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping function is printing, not returning values, so when you iterate the `map` object, `i` is being set to `None` over and over (`None` is returned by any function that doesn't explicitly `return` something else). To fix, change your function definition to something like:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    return args, kwargs
```

so it returns the values rather than printing them, and your loop's `print` will see them instead of `None`s.

Alternatively, leave the function as is, and change the loop to:

```
for i in obj:
    pass
```

so you don't print the useless `None`s from `test. This is generally bad style mind you;`map`'s mapping function should be side-effect free (`print`ing is a side-effect) to match the functional nature of`map`. In general, functions that`print`instead of`return`ing are bad ideas; if you`return`, the caller can`print`if they want to, or use a`return`value programmatically, but if you`print`, the caller can't really do much (even if they capture it through cheesy hacks, they're stuck parsing it to do anything useful with it).

Comment: thank you! But now it returns it in a tuple, like `((2,), {'var': 1})`. Is there any way to get around that? I tried `return args` and `return kwargs` on the next line but it only returned `args`.

Comment: @rassar: Multiple return values are always `tuple`s, you can't avoid that (`return` can really only return one thing, the comma just makes it produces a `tuple` of all the things as that "one thing"). But you could change your loop to `for a, b in obj: print(a, b)` to untuple as it loops, or `for i in obj: print(*i)` to unpack in the `print` call. Python's sequence unpacking is what makes multiple returns able to be used in ways that hide the `tuple`y aspect.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `test` does not return anything, thus it returns `None`. So after running

```
obj = map(lambda var: test(var+1, var = var), [1, 2, 3])
```

You will actually get `obj` with `[None, None, None]`.

Perhaps you want to return instead of print in your function:

```
def test(*args, **kwargs):
    return (args, kwargs)
```

Comment: is there a way to make it not return a tuple?

Comment: @rassar What do you want it to return?

Comment: just `args` and `kwargs` not in a tuple, like it is in the original. `(2,), {'var': 1}` instead of `((2,), {'var': 1})`. Is that not how python return works?

Comment: returning multiple values will always be in the form of a tuple. You just need to unpack it in your for loop instead.